# Unable to get Tailwind CSS or Intellisense to function

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I cannot get my react app to style divs using Tailwind, nor will the intellisense suggest any styling for me.

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
   <div className="text-red-400">Hello World</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [],
  darkMode: 'media', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

craco.config

```js
module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcssOptions: {
            plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer'),
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

I expect the text to be red using this, but instead it remains white. I've tried installing Intellisense for CSS alongside Tailwind CSS IntelliSense to no avail.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the latest Tailwind CSS (v3)?

Comment: Wasn't aware I was using an outdated version. Not sure how to check but I ran `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss autoprefixer` to get the latest version but still having the same issues.

Comment: ran `npm list` and it returned:  tailwindcss@3.0.23 @Ed Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind funcitonality fixed by changing the tailwind.config.js: You need to use `content: []` and delete `purge: []` and input components in the array, I also deleted mode: 'jit', since it's baked into Tailwind 3.0.  Corrected version below:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./public/**/*.html',
  './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}'],
  darkMode: 'media', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Still unable to get IntelliSense working however